# Generating Signed APK fails for React Native Project

Tags: react-native

I am getting an error > Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
Putting task artifact state for task ':app:processReleaseResources' into context took 0.0 secs.
file or directory '/Users/apple/Desktop/MyParkkingAppLocalRepo/the-parkking-reactnative/android/app/libs', not found
file or directory '/Users/apple/Desktop/MyParkkingAppLocalRepo/the-parkking-reactnative/android/app/libs', not found

while generating the signed APK for react native project as i am following the instructions given on https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html. How to fix it??

Comment: Please format you code and don't keep the main information hidden behind links. Add it to your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your SDK version. Sometimes this error happened when your build.gradle sdk version mismatched with your installed SDK.